# JavaScript Data Parser is Mixing values

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, graphics

im working on a WEB Based System and I'm using JavaScript Application from amcharts.com for creating a graphic which gets its value from a CVS file and is parsing them, then plot them. In CSV I have time and value column. Time format is hour:minute:second. For example value in time column can be  5:07:38

Here it the part that is parsing data:

```
    // method which parses csv data

    function parseCSV(data){ 

        //replace UNIX new lines

        data = data.replace (/\r\n/g, "\n");

        //replace MAC new lines

        data = data.replace (/\r/g, "\n");

        //split into rows

        var rows = data.split("\n");

        // create array which will hold our data:

        dataProvider = []   

        // loop through all rows

        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){

            // this line helps to skip empty rows

            if (rows[i]) {                    

                // our columns are separated by comma

                var column = rows[i].split(",");  

                // column is array now 

                // first item is date

                var date = column[2];

                // second item is value of the second column

                var value1 = column[3];

                // create object which contains all these items:

                var dataObject = {date:date, value1:value1};

                // add object to dataProvider array

                dataProvider.push(dataObject);

            }

        }

        // set data provider to the chart

        chart.dataProvider = dataProvider;

        // this will force chart to rebuild using new data            

        chart.validateData();
    }
```

In a result i get graphic with mixed places of time. 
For example:

5:19:11 5:03:12 5:05:12 5:07:12 5:12:11 5:14:11 5:16:11 5:18:11

Any idea hot to make them to become in right order as they are in CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean CSV file?

If it is, maybe you should use this [CSVToArray](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm).

You can not use the `split` for CSV data directly, because the data maybe contain the split char.